# Adding a new column which depends on other elements in the same row

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem with handling my dataset in Mathematica. Basically, I just want to create a new column "newColumn" which depends on 2 other columns, "a" and "b". But the values in "a" can either be x or y. If it is x, I want to write b^2 into my new column and otherwise sqrt(b).

Thanks, I really appreciate any help!

A small example would be:

column "a": x,y,y,x
column "b": 1,3,4,5

and then my new column should be: 1,sqrt(3),2,25

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add screenshots of my datasat in Mathematica. But unfortunately, it's not possible yet - I need a better reputation first ;-)

Comment: Do you have your data in a nested list?  If so, just printing the data item should give you a text string that you can include.  What I really want to know is the format of your data.  For the example above is it a 4X2 matrix?

Comment: The string (including the column I want to create out of the first two columns) is: dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "newColumn" -> 1|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "newColumn" -> Sqrt[2]|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "newColumn" -> 16|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "y", "newColumn" -> 3|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "newColumn" -> Sqrt[5]|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "x", "newColumn" -> 36|>}]

Comment: Exactly, 4x2. Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Ok, so you are using "Dataset", it's important to mention that.

Comment: @PatrickBalada you should edit the question to clarify instead of using commets.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (example = { { x, 1 } , {y, 3} , {y, 4} , {x, 5 } }) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
 (Switch[ #[[1]] , y  , Sqrt[#[[2]]] , x , #[[2]]^2] & /@ example )//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: The OP's question is about `Dataset`, although like you I initially thought it was a question about adding a column to a matrix.

Comment: Wow - this was quick :-) It looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for that. Just one more question. My goal is indeed to add the column "newColumn" to the dataset. Do you know, how I can add the column you created to my dataset? Thanks again, I really appreciate it!